# Can we implement SSO plugins in graylog version 5?

Tags: google-oauth, single-sign-on, graylog, graylog2, graylog3

I wanted to implement SSO plugins in graylog version 5.
Don't want to go with LDAP or AD.

When i insert plugins in graylog 5 server will not start . it shows an error
is their any way to insert plugins in graylog version 5.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have avalaible oidc or saml via ADFS or keycloak? Graylog free has only  Trusted header authentication. So for example you can use Apache as reverse proxy with mod_auth_openidc or mod_auth_mellon. Free Graylog does not sync groups